# I can't install numpy in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Which Python version do you use? For some reason it tries to build `numpy` locally instead of downloading a pre-compiled wheel and fails as you have no compiler installed.

Comment: Use Anaconda to get Python and all numerical packages recompiled (and easy to have different environments: also different python versions, and you can also have R, node.js, etc.). PyCharm and Anaconda are collaborating into integrating much more the two tools.

Comment: Have you tried to install mentioned build tools?